# Getting error; The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object? Function()'

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart

I am turning a stream into `Widgets` using the `StreamBuilder`, but I get my string in the operator highlighted and with the error:

`The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object? Function()`

This is the code:

```
void messageStream() async {
  await for (var snapshot in _firestore.collection('messages').snapshots()) {
    for (var message in snapshot.docs) {
      print(message.data());
    }
  }
}


    body: SafeArea(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: _firestore.collection('messages').snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) { //This is where the second error appeared
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                final messages = snapshot.data?.docs;
                List<Text> messageWidgets = [];
                for (var message in messages!) {
                  final messageText = message.data['text']; //These are where the errors can be found
                  final messageSender = message.data['sender'];//These are where the errors can be found.

                  final messageWidget = Text('$messageText from $messageSender');
                  messageWidgets.add(messageWidget);
                }
                return Column(
                  children: messageWidgets,
                );
              }
              return build(context);
            },
          ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.data` is a *function*. So, you have to call it using parenthesis `()`. Additionally, you might have to cast the correct type using the `as` keyword.

Instead of:

```
final messageText = message.data['text'];
final messageSender = message.data['sender'];
```

Try:

```
final messageText = (message.data() as Map)['text'];
final messageSender = (message.data() as Map)['sender'];
```

---

Or: you can use `.get()`:

```
final messageText = message.get('text');
final messageSender = message.get('sender');
```

Comment: I have edited my question it is about the last line of code where I return build(context), initially I had an error saying; "The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'Widget', is a potentially non-nullable type" so I decided to do return build(context)... am I correct about this? or what should I have done if I wasn't

Comment: @Fred_Wolfe Yes, you should add the `return` keyword to fix that error.